# Get Partition name from subquery dynamically?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get information from the most recent partition created on that table. Get dynamically instead of using the name like below

```
select *
from dw.DWT509_DADOS_NCLIE partition ('Partition Name').

select *
from dw.DWT509_DADOS_NCLIE partition 

(Select PARTITION_NAME
                  From (
                        Select PARTITION_POSITION, PARTITION_NAME, 
                               Max(PARTITION_POSITION) over (partition by TABLE_NAME) 
                            As MAX_P
                        From SYS.all_tab_partitions
                        Where TABLE_NAME='DWT509_DADOS_NCLIE'
                              --And Nvl(NUM_ROWS,0) = 0
                       )
                  Where PARTITION_POSITION = MAX_P);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Barbaros for your help with formating. Manny thank's.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use dynamic sql string...

```
declare
  l t.x%type;
  stmt varchar2(1000);
  part varchar2(30);

begin
  select max(x) into l from t;
  stmt := 'select max(uo.subobject_name)
from   t partition for (' || l || '), user_objects uo
where  dbms_rowid.rowid_object(t.rowid) = uo.data_object_id';

  execute immediate stmt into part;

  dbms_output.put_line(part);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it was possible to get the desired partition name using a subquery : Instead of 'SELECT * FROM [TABLE] PARTITION ('NAME')', having 'SELECT * FROM [TABLE] PARTITION (subquery to get partition name). So that isn't possible at all?

Comment: Is there the possibility to get it from a Function? like 'SELECT * FROM [TABLE] PARTITION (Function_GetPartitionName('Owner','TableName')?